# Creating a master detail page using unorderedlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have this class below and was able to populate it with data. DelMaster and DelDetails have related data.
    Not worried about the data

```
        public class Deliverables
        {
            public DeliverablesMaster DelMaster { get; set; }
            public List<DeliverablesDetails> DelDetails { get; set; }
        }
```

Below are the properties of the master. I will only be displaying two fields

```
        public class DeliverablesMaster
        {
            public string  ProjectDeliverablesId { get; set; }
            public string  ProjectId { get; set; }
            public string  DeliverableCategory { get; set; }
            public string  DeliverableText { get; set; }
            public string  DeliverableOrder { get; set; }
            public string  UpsizeTs { get; set; }        
        }
```

Below are the properties of the details/children and will be displaying all the fields in one row

```
        public class DeliverablesDetails
        {
            public string  ProjectDelivStatusId { get; set; }
            public string  ProjectDeliverableSID { get; set; }
            public string  PDSText { get; set; }
            public string  PDSCurrency { get; set; }        
        }
```

I want to be able to display this in an unordered list with the parent at the top as a header and the 
    children below. I know it will look like something below but not sure how to put this together.
    How can I put these foreach statements together? I am more concerned about the foreach statements.

```
        foreach ()
                {
                <ul>
                    <li>

                    </li>
                    @foreach ()
                    { 
                        <li>
                            <ul>
                                <li> </li>
                                <li> </li>
                                <li> </li>
                                <li> </li>                                  
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your classs' design is wrong, if there is a master/details model, it needs to use Hierarchical model for it. check out this:

```
 public class DeliverablesMaster 
        {
            public long    DelMasterId {get; set;}
            public string  ProjectDeliverablesId { get; set; }
            public string  ProjectId { get; set; }
            public string  DeliverableCategory { get; set; }
            public string  DeliverableText { get; set; }
            public string  DeliverableOrder { get; set; }
            public string  UpsizeTs { get; set; }  

            public List<DeliverablesDetails> DelDetails { get; set; }
        }


  public class DeliverablesDetails
        {
            public string  DelDetailId {get; set;}
            public string  ProjectDelivStatusId { get; set; }
            public string  ProjectDeliverableSID { get; set; }
            public string  PDSText { get; set; }
            public string  PDSCurrency { get; set; } 
            public long   DelMasterId  {get; set;}
            public DeliverablesMaster  DelMaster  {get; set;}

        }
```

Then you could use foreach to access them :

```
  @foreach (var m in DeliverablesMaster )
            {
                <ul>
                <li>                  </li>

                @foreach (var d in m.DelDetails )
                {

                   <li>
                        <ul>
                            <li> </li>
                            <li> </li>
                            <li> </li>
                            <li> </li>                                  
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                  }
                </ul>
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need to have both of the classes in one model right? How do i combine this in one model.

Comment: Maybe,If I know for what you want to have these in one model, i would help you. in this model (hierarchical  model)you can access to both of them with the master class.

Comment: Thats true and i can see that. I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: Another question I have for you is that why do you have this in the DeliverablesDetails class  (public DeliverablesMaster  DelMaster  {get; set;}
)

Comment: In the master I have one record with a primary and in the details an associated foreign key with multiple records. How can I write the query and populate the DeliverablesMaster model above?

Comment: Child class should have a foreign key and a navigation property, then it can points back to its parent. DelMasterId  is foreign Key and the DeliverablesMaster  collection is its navigation property.

Comment: for access to your collection from  DeliverablesMaster  model and get the DeliverablesMaster parent from DeliverablesDetails , define  the collection and navigation property virtual . 
            public virtual DeliverablesMaster  DelMaster  {get; set;}
            public virtual List<DeliverablesDetails> DelDetails { get; set; }